# Get only one row from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables. Primary key from table A is primary key in table B with another column.

So structure is like this.

```
Table A
id - PRIMARY
total_amount

Table B
id - PRIMARY
another_id PRIMARY
status
```

So i can have id from table A appear multiple times in table B.
My problem is that this query

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total_amount), 0) AS amount
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 10
AND status <> 'UNKNOWN'
```

sometimes returns more in amount the it should. 
If total_amount on id 10 is 2, and that same id 10 repeats in table b three times my amount will be 6 instead of 2.

Is there a way I can avoid that. Some other way to write this query.

Thank you.

Comment: No its composite primary key with another col.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists` instead:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total_amount), 0) AS amount
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableB AS b
              WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.status <> 'UNKNOWN'
             );
```

Comment: EXISTS is quite slow and these two tables are quite big :) so this might be a problem for me.

Comment: `exists` should actually be among the fastest methods, if you have an index `tableb(id, status)`.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT the list of ids returned from tableB

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(SUM(total_amount), 0) AS amount
FROM 
    tableA AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tableB WHERE [status] <> 'UNKNOWN') AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.id = 10
```